# PHP rewrite URL htaccess multiple conditions

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite URL addresses but I have not made much progress.
I read a lot and tried, but I did not manage to do what I want. I would be glad if someone gave an idea how it could be.
What I want to do is:

1. Remove "**.php**" extension, for ex. "**site.com/about**"
2. If i type "**site.com/index.php**" or "**site.com/index**" to
   redirect to "**site.com**"
3. If i type "**site.com/profile.php?profile=alex**" to rewrite URL to "**site.com/profile/alex**"

Also keep the path of the files that I'm include such as css, js, images or php.

What I have tried separately:

1.
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

2.
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`

3.
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)[/]?$ profile.php?profile=$1`

Comment: Why not rewrite all requests to index.php and use a [router](http://altorouter.com/).

Comment: Hi @Jaquarh thanks for the advice, but the code is mostly Inline.

Comment: @anubhava yes, for 1., I  try `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` 2. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` and 3. `RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)[/]?$ profile.php?profile=$1`

Comment: Please edit your question show your attempted .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?profile=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?profile=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes, it works except when I'm on **site.com/profile/alex** the css, js, images, and url path is wrong. Trying to load them from **site.com/profile/about** , **site.com/profile/css/style.css** and so on.

Comment: For css/js issue, you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. God bless you. And one last question of pure curiosity. Is there an option instead of the **site.com/profile/alex** to be **site.com/alex** ?

Comment: Hi again, I want to ask you something else if it is possible.
I have categories that load the content dynamically(AJAX). Categories are static and will not change, they are 3(Movies, Books and Cards).
I try to make if I type site.com/movies to redirect me to the index page with category so I can get the parameter and submit via AJAX and then load the content.
Is it possible to add these categories to the htaccess file and, if entered, to redirect to the index/category(site.com/movies)?
Will this create collisions with other conditions for profile?
I'd be glad to hear your advice. Thanks.

Comment: You can have URIs like `/category/abcd` and have it rewritten to something like `/index.php?cat=abcd`. That rule should be placed before `# internal forward` line.

Comment: Hi anubhava, thank you for the advice. The category in the link also does not look bad, but I'm worried about SEO. Will not it be better without the category in the address? Can you tell me some sample code for a category and without category if is possible? Thanks again.

Comment: What should my condition be in the htaccess file? I try this before # internal forward from .. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Just one connection: `RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]`